# Firefox Extension How to pass string type variable into javascript replace regex parameter?

Tags: javascript, regex, firefox, firefox-addon

I've been working on firefox extension for several days now and there is one thing I can't solve.

I generate a list of regex and I wanted to pass that string into replace function in javascript (in the regex parameters). Here is the example of the string:

```
/(https?:\/\/(www\.)?rapidgator\.net\b([-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]*))/g
/(https?:\/\/(www\.)?ul\.to\b([-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]*))/g
/(https?:\/\/(www\.)?uploadable\.ch\b([-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]*))/g
/(https?:\/\/(www\.)?180upload\.com\b([-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]*))/g
```

For a convenient way, lets make it this way. I managed to get the file and get the first line of the string and assign it into a variable:

```
var rapidgator = "/(https?:\/\/(www\.)?rapidgator\.net\b([-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]*))/g";
```

I want the string to be a "replace parameter" like this:

```
var rep = rep.replace(rapidgator,"<a href='$1'>$1</a>");
```

But I cant get that work.

I've been trying to use RegExp object and that didn't work to.

```
var rapidgator = new RegExp("(https?:\/\/(www\.)?rapidgator\.net\b([-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]*))", "g");
```

How to make that work? Thank you for your advice :)

Comment: You need to escape the \ one more time while passing your regex inside `"` quotes.

Comment: `var rapidgator = new RegExp("(https?://(www\\.)?rapidgator\\.net\\b([-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\\\\+.~#?&/=]*))", "g");`

Comment: [Accept anyone of the answers from here which helps you the most](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer).

Answer (score 1):

If you can get the regex, why not let it remain a regex literal?

```
var rapidgator = /(https?:\/\/(www\.)?rapidgator\.net\b([-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]*))/g;
```

If you want to make it through `RegExp` constructor, make sure you escape `\` with another backslash and you don't need delimiters and the second argument takes the flags.

As in

```
var rapidgator = new RegExp("(https?:\\/\\/(www\\.)?rapidgator\\.net\\b([-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]*))","g")
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape the backslash one more time when passing your regex within double quotes.

```
var rapidgator = new RegExp("(https?://(www\\.)?rapidgator\\.net\\b([-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\\\\+.~#?&/=]*))", "g");
```

And also to match a backslash, you need to escape it exactly three times.